# Relating the Dirichlet $\beta$-function to the $\zeta$-function through the Parseval theorem. Is this theorem reversible?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, integral-transforms, dirichlet-series

On the Wiki-page about the [Dirichlet $\beta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function), it is noted that "*this function is also the simplest example of a series non-directly related to $\zeta(s)$ which can also be factorized as an Euler product.*"

The $\beta$-function is defined as:

$$\beta(s)=\displaystyle \small \sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-2x}+1}dx=
4^{-s}\big(\zeta\left(s,\frac14\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac34\right)\big) $$

hence it is directly related to the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) (but not to $\zeta(s)\,$). However, after applying [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) to the Fourier/Laplace transform of the integral for $\Gamma(s)\,\beta(s)$ I get:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta\left(s+x\,i\right)\Gamma\left(s+x\,i\right)\beta\left(s-x\,i\right)\Gamma\left(s-x\,i\right)dx=\int_0^\infty x^{2s-1}\frac{e^{2x}}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}dx$$

for $s \in \mathbb{C}, \Re(s)>0$. The RHS can be simplified into the closed form: $$\frac{\Gamma(2s)}{2^{2s}}\,\eta(2s-1)$$
with $\eta(z)=(1-2^{1-z})\,\zeta(z)$ the [Dirichlet $\eta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

So, it seems that $\Gamma(s)\,\beta(s)$ could be transformed into an expression with $\Gamma(2s)$ and $\zeta(2s-1)$ and I wondered whether a reverse route exists as well (i.e. to transform $\zeta(s)$ back into $\beta(s)\,$ to reflect maybe duality)? Does e.g. a "square root" equivalent for the Parseval theorem exist?